# How to see hardlink count on a file and store to a Variable UNIX

Tags: bash, function, unix

I am currently writing a bash script that needs to test if a file has any hard links associated with it.

So far I know that ***ls -l*** will give me the count in the second column of info. Is there anyway to pull that number from there so that it can be stored in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the output of a command into a variable you'll use so called [*command substitution*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Btw, I would use the `stat` command instead of `ls`:

```
number_of_links=$(stat -c %h filename)
```

Check [`man stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)